# Советы по написанию эмулятора простого процессора

Tags: эмулятор, прерывания, intel

Уже нагуглил спеки i4004, сижу изучаю.

Расскажите мне как это лучше сделать?

Напишу генератор, который будет принимать схему содержащую:

- Описания размера байта (да, он не везде 8-битный), размер слова.
- Кол-во, размер и имена регистров
- Набор операций, с описанием опкодов, и тут же реализация этих операций.
- Длительность выполнения каждой операции.
- Доступная память.

По этой схеме будет генерироваться код для выполнения операций, чтения опкодов.

Я ещё не дочитал спек, были ли в i4004 прерывания, но хочу сделать в этом эмуляторе поддержку прерываний. Как их лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом простейшем виде делается таким образом.

1. По схеме процессора определяются необходимые блоки (регистры общего назначения, регистры флагов, счетчик инструкций и т.п.) и под них создаются объекты кода.
2. Выбирается способ хранения в памяти машинного кода, например, простой массив.
3. Выбирается способ декодирования машинных кодов, например, таблица переходов или таблица функций.
4. Реализуется бесконечный цикл, в котором таблица исполняет машинный код.

В качестве упражнения по программированию, этого будет вполне достаточно. Если нужно сделать что-то более серьезное, стоит изучить код уже существующих эмуляторов, например, qemu.

[Пример реализации](http://code.google.com/p/armware/) эмулятора ARM-процессора на Google-коде.

Comment: "Выбирается способ декодирования машинных кодов, например, таблица переходов или таблица функций." Можно подробнее? Кроме того, у вас есть идеи по поводу прерываний?

Comment: По таблицам обстоятельно написано в википедии: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_table. Как вариант, это switch по опкодам. Программные прерывания - это обычные опкоды, а аппаратные прерывания - это дополнительные блоки, которые обновляются по внешнему воздействию. Чтобы добиться асинхронности прерываний, возможно, работу с ними стоит вынести в отдельный поток.

Comment: Таблица переходов\функций - это просто классика :) Просто таблица.. в ней адреса функций, которые реализуют необходимые инструкции. Тогда по коду инструкции можно просто вызывать функцию из таблицы. По поводу прерываний, то тут по ходу придётся проверять после выполнения каждой инструкции какой-нибудь флаг (а нет ли прерываний). Не очень эффективно, но ничего не поделать.

Comment: По поводу внешних прерываний, по сути еще нужен некий эмулятор
среды (аппаратуры, связанной с процессором), которая 'живет'
в потоке времени эмулируемого процессора. Тут нужно понять,
как часто вызывать подпрограммы эмулирующие внешние устройства
по ходу исполнения команд процессора в общем цикле исполнения 
машинного кода.

Comment: Я не знал что она называется jump table. Про отдельный поток я тоже думал -- вроде так лучше. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Каждая команда выполняется в несколько этапов:

1. Извлечение опкода из ОЗУ.
2. Декодирование.
3. Извлечение операндов из ОЗУ.
4. Выполнение операции.
5. Сохранение результата.

Можно после каждого этапа проверять состояние регистра прерываний( или как он там называется). К тому же данная схема хорошо декомпозируют систему на блоки :-)